# Set first value of dynamic HTML option to empty

Tags: php

```
<select id="section" name="section">
    <?php
    include("Nethost.php");
    $section = "";
    $yr = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM section ORDER BY yrlvl, section");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $section = $row['section'];
        $yr = $row['yrlvl'];
        ?>
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option <?php $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT section FROM student WHERE idnumber = '$idnumber'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) { ?>
            selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="<?php print $section; ?>"><?php print $yr; ?> - <?php print $section; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Above is the php code of the select option. Populated with data from database table, how can I set that the first value if empty. I tried adding a Select but this is the result[image].

The option *select* keeps repeating. What to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<select id="section" name="section">
    <?php
    include("Nethost.php");
    $section = "";
    $yr = "";
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM section ORDER BY yrlvl, section");
    ?>
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $section = $row['section'];
        $yr = $row['yrlvl'];
        ?>

        <option <?php $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT section FROM student WHERE idnumber = '$idnumber'");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) { ?>
            selected="selected" <?php } ?> value="<?php print $section; ?>"><?php print $yr; ?> - <?php print $section; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Aw. Just putting it outside the while loop. Thank you.

Comment: :) ya, if this fixed your problem, please remember to mark the answer correct

Comment: Yes. I still have a minute to mark it as answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just move that option line "*Select*" out of your php code:

```
<select id="section" name="section">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
    ...your php code
    ?>
</select>
```